# Is there a Don't Care value for lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to use `count()` where you are looking for a specific value in the nested list and not caring about the rest?

```
lst = [[1,6],[1,4],[3,4],[1,2]]
X = 1
lst.count([X, _ ])
```

This would return a count of `3`, since there are three nested lists that have a `1` in the first index.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Don't name your variables `list` because it will overwrite the `list` type. To answer your question, no. The idiomatic way to do this would be to use a list comprehension or generator: `len([x for x in myList if x[0] == 1])` or `sum(1 if x[0]==1 else 0 for x in myList)`

Comment: There is no. Your are approaching it from the other side though - it is not about the values, it is about the functionality that you are looking for, specifically, find the number of lists in a list of lists that have a specific first element.

Comment: @pault It overrides the `list` type? Well they're using a `list` so clearly the type still exists! It overrides the `list()` constructor **function**!

Comment: @pault For the sake of cutting out the unneeded `else`, I'd rewrite that generator expression to `sum(1 for x in myList if x[0] == 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the length of a filtered list:

```
my_list = [[1,6][1,4][3,4][1,2]]
X = 1
len([q for q in my_list if q[0] == X])
```

Or, if you prefer to use `count`, then make a list of the items you *do* care about:

```
[q[0] for q in my_list].count(X)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use some sneaky `sum()` hacks:

```
sum(k[0] == X for k in your_list)
```

I.e.

```
>>> X = 1
>>> your_list = [[1,6],[1,4],[3,4],[1,2]]
>>> sum(k[0] == X for k in your_list)
3
```

---

**why?**

The section: `k[0] == X for k in your_list` is a generator expression that yields `True` for each element in `your_list` which has first element equal to your `X`. The `sum()` function takes the values and treats a `True` as a `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do `len(filter(lambda x: x[0] == 1, lst))`

But be careful, if your list contains an element that is not a list (or an empty list) it will throw an exception! This could be handled by adding two additional conditions

`len(filter(lambda x: type(x) == list and len(x) > 0 and x[0] == 1, lst))`

Answer (score 2):

Counting how often one value occurs in the first position requires a full pass over the list, so if you plan to use the potential `countfunction(inputlist, target)` more than once on the same list, it's more efficient to build a dictionary holding all the counts (also requiring one pass) which you can subsequently query with O(1).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> lst = [[1,6],[1,4],[3,4],[1,2]]
>>> c = Counter(map(itemgetter(0), lst))
>>> c[1]
3
>>> c[3]
1
>>> c[512]
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have shown good ways to approach this problem using python built-ins, but you can use `numpy` if what you're actually after is fancy indexing.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
lst = np.array([[1,6],[1,4],[3,4],[1,2]])
print(lst)
#array([[1, 6],
#       [1, 4],
#       [3, 4],
#       [1, 2]])
```

In this case `lst` is a `numpy.ndarray` with shape `(4,2)` (4 rows and 2 columns). If you want to count the number of rows where the first column (index 0) is equal to `X`, you can write:

```
X = 1
print((lst[:,0] == X).sum())
#3
```

The first part `lst[:,0]` means grab all rows and only the first index.

```
print(lst[:,0])
#[1 1 3 1]
```

Then you check which of these is equal to `X`:

```
print(lst[:,0]==X)
#[ True  True False  True]
```

Finally sum the resultant array to get the count. (There is an implicit conversion from `bool` to `int` for the sum.)